# Sheer UI OnLoad Method to run another method to Dynamically Change UI Text

Tags: sitecore-client, sheer-ui, commands, scheduler-job

I am currently working on a custom `DialogForm` that will display a progress status based on a particular number of Sitecore Job Progress running in the background and dynamically updating the UI part of the form.

The problem is inside the method `OnLoad` of my custom `DialogForm` where I called the another custom method, it didn't execute what my method is expected in which I also tried just displaying an `Alert` Message.

Can someone give me recommendation how to properly do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (!Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
        {
            var jobsRunning = JobManager.GetJobs().Where(xjob => xjob.IsDone == false && xjob.Name.StartsWith("SomeJob")).ToList();
            int initialCount = jobsRunning.Count;

            MyCustomMethod();

        }

    }
protected void MyCustomMethod()
    {

        var jobsRunning = JobManager.GetJobs().Where(xjob => xjob.IsDone == false && xjob.Name.StartsWith("SomeJob")).ToList();

        SheerResponse.Timer("CheckStatus", 500);
    }


    protected void CheckStatus()
    {
        var jobList = JobManager.GetJobs().Where(xjob => xjob.IsDone == false && xjob.Name.StartsWith("SomeJob")).ToList();
        Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Checking Status");
        if (jobList != null)
        {

            Progress_Counter.Text = string.Format("Job Progress(s) : {0}...", jobRemaining);
            SheerResponse.Timer("CheckStatus", 500);
            Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Checking Count");

        }
        else
        {
            Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Task Completed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happened if you add it to the `OnPreRender`. Override the `OnPreRender` and add the method `CheckStatus()`

Comment: I've tried it on OnPreRender and the method is being run through but still doesn't execute even showing an Alert.